# *Programmatically* using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there any documentation (or sample code) that explains how I can use Spring Security *without* Spring; i.e. without any Spring annotations, configuring and registering the filters etc. programmatically?

In particular, I would like to use it with embedded Tomcat where, also, I am configuring all the servlets programmatically without annotations, classpath searching etc.

Comment: What is the point of this approach?

Comment: Also remember that https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic it is not allowed to ask for specific tutorials, books etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, it is called the spring framework official documentation.

Your question is extremly wide so no we cant give a more detailed answer than that

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/